# Excel vba Copy last line of detail line into subtotal line

Tags: excel, vba

I run a vba script with a subtotal function. The script also copies the last line from the detail into the subtotal lines (on non-numeric lines).

```
     With sht
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy comment information to subtotal line
        Range("C2:G2" & LastRow).Offset(-1, 0).Select
        'Range("Z2:AA2" & LastRow).Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
     End With
```

This works well on lines where there is data in the detail right above it. It doesn't work when the detail line is null - it will reach up until it finds something and copy it down.

TIA.

Comment: You're using `With`, but not connecting that with the `Range` objects. Add a period before all `Range` objects, e.g. `LastRow = .Cells()`, `.Range("C2:G2" & lastRow)`, etc. ...also, do you mean to do `.Range("C2:G" & lastRow)`? Finally, you could likely do this in two lines.  Get your lastRow, then `.Range("C2:G" & LastRow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"`.

Comment: Thanks Batman. I used your single line and it works, but the problem is the same. If there is no line in the detail preceding the subtotal line, the code will reach back until it finds a value to copy down. I want it to go back only to the row preceding the subtotal line.

Comment: Does you "subtotal" line have "Subtotal" in a row? Say the sum is going in `B20`, does it say "Subtotal" in say `A20`?

Comment: No, A20 has the client name, which is what was totaled on.